# Checking for attachments before sending the emails using VBA

Tags: vba, count, attachment

I have a macro to draft automatic emails based on the recipients in each columns.

However, I'm looking for a code which can if the attachments named in the excel sheet are attached to the email. If there is any attachment missing from that email  it should show a msg box with the name of the missing attachment. 
[SNip of one the sheets attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGDQb.png)

```
Sub Email1()



Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim FLNM As String
Dim AttchmentName As String
Set AddressList = Sheets("Tracker Summary").Range("Y:Z")

Dim AttchmentName1 As String
Dim path As String

Call FetchFileNames

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "/"

Dim i As Integer

i = 5

With olMail

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

    .Display
    .To = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value
    .CC = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, i).Value
    .Subject = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i).Value
    .HTMLBody = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, i).Value & .HTMLBody
    j = 6

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(j, i))

    On Error Resume Next

    FLNM = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i).Value

    AttchmentName1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FLNM, AddressList, 1, True)

    If FLNM = AttchmentName1 Then

    AttchmentName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FLNM, AddressList, 2, True)

    .Attachments.Add AttchmentName

    End If

    j = j + 1

    Loop

    '.Display

    End With

Sheets("Tracker Summary").Range("Y:Z").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `AttachmentName` is a full file path string, maybe your code could check if the file exists beforehand.

For the sake of simplicity...

```
If Len(Dir(AttachmentName)) = 0 then msgbox "The File " & AttachmentName & " is missing"
```

... Just after you set `AttachmentName` value at `AttchmentName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FLNM, AddressList, 2, True)`

Obviously, same for any other Attachment variables.

Comment: Thank you for the response Sir. But there is no path in the excel sheet. The user would save the reports with the naming convention provided in the excel sheet and save the report in the same folder where this macro is saved.

Let me know if you need the complete document